# Guide on Activity Diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Can anyone guide me how can I improve and change my activity diagram so it will be a correct format please.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/857/activitydiagram.png/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i don't link it, i would sub divide in smaller pieces for a better understanding and view...

```
ex:Camera Activated, gallery, favorites....
```

you should explain a little bit what are you doing ...

any way...

```
- your main menu just have menus? don't have any thing else?
- Gallery menu, goes to database but doesn't receive any thing
- Camera menu? what it does? the same as Gallery menu? is better to sub divide that
- if you already have it in the Favorite list, i would think better in what to do that..
```

i recommended to see this
 http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/activityDiagram.htm

Comment: Well on the activity diagram we do not need the explanation; when we draw the use case diagram and the description then that when the explanation goes...that is what I think..?

Comment: i mean.. you should explain to us for a better knowledge of your application

Comment: Ok thanks will do and put the link on here so you can see them, by the way you do not think the AD is correct?

Comment: as i told you, for me, the AD should be understandable... check the 1st answer.... for example-> Gallery menu, what it does? go to the database and then?. it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Parts of your diagram are better suited for a state diagram, while others would be better suited for a class or component diagram. I do understand the information you're trying to convey, but as an activity diagram it doesn't work.

With an activity diagram, you should think in terms of "first this happens, then that happens." The things that happen should be represented by the activities, not by the connectors between them; those are only there to show the order of the activities. Activity names should be verb phrases.

"Map Menu", "Gallery", these are noun phrases - you're referring to something that exists, not something that happens. "Camera Activated", that's a state; again, not something that happens. (A state *changing* is something that happens, but *being in* a state is not.)

Activites should have names like "Application starts", "User selects to open gallery", "User activates map", "Application retrieves map data from database" -- they should be things that happen. The things that perform the activities (user, application, database) aren't important in the activity diagram.

If you don't want to think in those terms, then simply use a different type of diagram.

Comment: Thank for the idea and inputs; I have change my AD at this link:

http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/9138/adigram.jpg

Can you please look them and see if this is correct? 
Thanks.